# Outgoing call is auto rejected

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox (2.6.3) in my app to implement video chat.Incoming call function  is successfully working but whenever i try to make a call (i.e outgoing call) to a specific user,the following method is called

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session rejectedByUser:(NSNumber *)userID userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
```

where as the receiver receives the call and before it accept the call the above method is called while receiver is unaware of rejection,and call is not ended on receiver side.Receiver is portal.
I set following parameters but i am not getting any success

```
[QBRTCConfig setAnswerTimeInterval:45];
[QBRTCConfig setDisconnectTimeInterval:30];
[QBRTCConfig setDialingTimeInterval:10];
[QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:true];
[QBSettings setReconnectTimerInterval:3];
```

Please help me what i am missing.Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide us full logs?

QuickbloxWebRTC does not send any reject by itself, it is only client code.

Comment: Hi...I have same problem. Have got any solutions?

Comment: yes,check that in your admin panel ,the id by which you created the account ,shouldn't be the admin id,you are calling.